# create queue using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus C# SDK

Tags: c#, azure

I traying to migrate a code from that use [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-bus), to [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/) library. Bye topics, hello queues. ServiceBus SDK, uses a ManagamentClient instance like this:

```
managementClient.CreateTopicAsync(TopicName);
```

[That method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.management.managementclient.createtopicasync?view=azure-dotnet) to create Topics, it also have a method named CreateQueue, that would fill good the need.

However, Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SDK seems has not such capabilities. Neither [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) makes reference to any equivalents. Seems that only via azure can be created new queues at services bus.

There is some way to create Queues using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus library?

Comment: Please look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` that is in the `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration` namespace. For example:

```
var adminClient = new Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration
    .ServiceBusAdministrationClient("your-connection-string");

await adminClient.CreateQueueAsync("newqueue")
await adminClient.CreateTopicAsync("newtopic");
```

Comment: Just Like that. Problems solved! You are the best Thanks